# How to configure the location of the Oracle password file?

Tags: oracle, linux

When I start an Oracle instance with `sqlplus` the paths to the datafiles are stored in the control files, the control file name is stored in the `control_files` initialization parameter. The initialization parameters are read from a file (`init.ora`, `spfile.ora`) found on a default location or their location can be passed to the database instance at startup (`sqlplus startup pfile=filename`, `spfile` parameter in the startup script). So all files needed by the database can be located at arbitrary positions and these positions can be communicated to the database instance at startup. But how about the password file? From the documentation we know that the default location for the password file in Linux is `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapw${ORACLE_SID}`. If it is a cluster we can tell the cluster software where we have stored the password file by `srvctl modify database -db <db_unique_name> -pwfile <password_file_path>`. But the name of the password file in this case can be arbitrary.

- can I place the password file on an arbitrary location and communicate this location to the database when I start the instance with `sqlplus`.
- So how does Oracle know where to find password file, especially if one starts the database with `sqlplus` or `rman` and not by the cluster software?
- Can I query the database to find out the location of the password file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. You can use symlinks, but that is not a feature of the database. And of course the passwordfile can be changed or moved while the database is online.
2. An instance started with `sqlplus` or `rman` uses the passwordfile
   defined with srvctl. They are not entirely independent of
   Grid Infrastructure, some integration between them exists. There are other examples: starting or stopping and instance with `sqlplus` or `rman` updates the target and state of the cluster resource in GI. Or creating an spfile from `sqlplus` updates the srvctl config of the database with the new location of the spfile. Without GI, the location of passwordfile is predetermined by the name of the instance and the value of `$ORACLE_BASE_CONFIG` (in case of a read-only Oracle Home) or `$ORACLE_HOME`.
3. `select file_name from x$kzsrpwfile;`

Comment: thank you, that was eactly the infomation that I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Even if this were possible, *why* would you want to do so?

With Oracle Database, you'll have [more than] enough to worry about *without* mucking about with system *defaults* that are, probably, best left well alone.
The less "surprises" you (or your successor) have in a Disaster Recovery situation at Stupid o'Clock in the Morning, the better.

Besides, only your DBAs (and Server Engineers) should be *anywhere near* your database server(s), so what does it *matter* where the DBMS chooses to put *its own* files?

Consider:
If you used Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) and you chose to put the wallet file containing the credentials somewhere non-standard and, for whatever reason, that file didn't get backed up?  If your server went "Boom!", you'd lose *everything*.

Comment: thank you for you answer but I am not interested on advise in administering databases but I want som technical insight it the topic described in my post. Besides that, the password file is a completly differnt matter than the wallet file  and its loss is much less critical than the loss of the wallet file. also the possibility to  query the location of the password file used by the database may be a useful feature in some situations.